# Self @ManytoMany relation, integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, database, jpa, playframework

I am using the [Play framewor](https://www.playframework.com/)k, and I am trying to set up a database scheme using [jpa](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) where a table has a many to many relationship with itself.

Here is how my entity looks like :

```
@Entity
public class User2 extends Model{
    public static Finder<Long, User2> find = new Finder<>(User2.class);

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    public long twitterId;

    @JoinTable(name = "following", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "idFollower", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)},
    inverseJoinColumns = {    @JoinColumn(name = "idFollowing", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    public List<User2> followingCollection = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And the related test :

```
public class User2Test {

    Application fakeApplication = Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase());

    @Test
    public void testManyToMany(){

        running(fakeApplication, () -> {
            User2 u = new User2();
            u.twitterId = 123456L;

            User2 u2 = new User2();
            u2.twitterId = 123457L;

            u.save();
            u2.save();

            u.followingCollection.add(u2);
            u.save();

            User2 u3 = User2.find.where().eq("twitterId", 123456L).findUnique();
            Assert.assertEquals(u3.followingCollection.size(), 1);

            u.delete();
            u2.delete();
            u3 = User2.find.where().eq("twitterId", 123456L).findUnique();
            Assert.assertNull(u3);

            u3 = User2.find.where().eq("twitterId", 123457L).findUnique();
            Assert.assertNull(u3);

        });
    }

}
```

But when I am trying to run the test, I get the following error :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_FOLLOWING_USER2_01: PUBLIC.FOLLOWING FOREIGN KEY(IDFOLLOWER) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USER2(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from user2 where id=? [23503-187]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:426)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:443)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:318)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:920)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:938)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:100)
```

The basic idea is :

- I have a bunch of users
- A User can follow other users
- In the best of worlds, deleting a users would delete its list of followers as well, but not the followers themselves....

What I have tried, without success so far : 
 - Invert the following/follower relation in the join table
 - Add a cascading type ALL

It looks to me like the join table refuses to remove relationships for existing users. I have read quite a few tutorials already, [including this one](http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2013/06/06/jpa-2-tutorial-many-to-many-with-self-2/) but so far I have been unsuccessful.

How can I avoid running into issues when deleting users ?

Thanks,